# Command line command won't run

Tags: c#, cmd

I am trying to make a UI for some of the new Windows 10 Commands that have become useful to us. I am trying to make a UI that has three text boxes, one for the computer name, the username, and the message in order to utilize the msg command. When I run the command on my normal CMD, I would type `msg /server:matthewl mlynch "hello"`,this will display a little message on my screen saying hello. However, when I try to run it from my c# ui, I get this

> 'msg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>       operable program or batch file.

As you can probably tell, this is not correct as it works when I launch command line and manually input but not when the UI runs the command.

Comment: Please show the code that isn't working. How are you launching the `cmd.exe` process from your UI code?

Comment: Are you including the path to msg.exe from your C# program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, coworker helped me, it was a setting in Project>Project Properties>Build>Platform Target and changed that to x64. Apparently it wasn't opening C:\Windows\System32, it was actually opening C:\Windows\Syswow64 but labeling itself as system32.

Answer (score 0):

To run these commands, normally you'd use the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class to start the `cmd.exe` process, and then pass the command to the window:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", 
    $"/C msg /server:{txtServer.Text} {txtUser.Text} \"{txtMessage.Text}\"");
```